# Would restarting while Windows Update is running cause corruption?

Tags: windows, windows-update

I have some work I need to do, and a feature isn´t working. I think I have to restart, but Windows Update is (of course) ruining everything. Can I restart?
It really shouldn´t be a problem, but considering Windows is notoriously retarded I´m not certain...
It’s a background feature update.

Comment: If you are able to restart using the start menu, not a problem.  If you are not on the desktop looking at the spinning bead thingies, I would not restart during an update unless I had to.  Yes, it can cause corruption.  I am not aware of any operating systems that you can reboot in the middle of an update and not risk hosing everything.

Comment: Usually ther isn't unless forced. The option update and reboor should do what you want safely but you need to let it finish the tasks.

Comment: Do NOT interrupt Windows Update. Only start getting worried tomorrow morning.

Comment: I want to add that this is a background windows update. I can still use my pc.  I suppose that doesn’t really change anything though?

Comment: What update is pending and/or being installed?  If a cumulative update is being downloaded/installed then your system can be updated without a problem.  if Windows is attempting to prepare your system to install a feature update you should not interrupt the process, depending on what stage it is at.  Edit your question, indicate the exact update that is being installed, to the body of your question.  Do not supply this vital information in a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't force stop a Windows update in progress. Force stopping a Windows update in its tracks can damage your Windows install and make Windows unusable. Instead, let the update finish, then either uninstall it or use Windows' various rollback and reset options.

If you've not quite reached the point where the Windows update is installing, but it's downloaded and the shutdown and reset options have been replaced by *Update and Shut Down* and *Update and Restart*, you can still stop these updates before they're applied by stopping Windows' own maintenance from taking place as follows.

1. Search for *Control Panel* in the Windows search box and select it.
2. Select *System and Security* from the list of menu options.
3. Select *Security and Maintenance*.
4. Click the downward unfold button <sup>╲╱</sup> to the right of *Maintenance* to unfold its options.
5. Under the heading *Automatic Maintenance*, select *Stop maintenance*. That should stop the update process in its tracks. To turn maintenance back on again select *Start maintenance* instead of *Stop maintenance*.

   [image: Control Panel>Security and Maintenance>Security and Maintenance]

<sub>**Source:** revised from [How to stop Windows 10 updates in progress](https://web.archive.org/web/20200530132911/https://www.lifewire.com/how-to-stop-windows-10-updates-in-progress-4584382)</sub>